# finding the last (duplicate) string in .txt file with vb

Tags: vbscript

(I'm quite new to `vb`, but familiar with `vba`).

I'm trying to find out how to read a text file from bottom to top as:
the text file is updated 'x' period of time; lines being added,
and I need to find the last entry "line" that contains the contains the text "System Pass". However between the last line of the file and the last line that contains the needed string are a lot unnecessary "dump" lines.

With excel I used to import the text file and loop through the rows starting at the bottom and to determine if I had the correct string line with the `inStr` function. But this doesn't work, or I just simply don't know how to convert the code to `vb`.

Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks 
Philippe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to read a txt file into an array and poll through it from bottom to top using instr to search for text:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\test.txt", ForReading)

strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

MyArray = Split(strText, vbCrLf)

For X = Ubound(MyArray) to lbound(MyArray) step -1
    If instr(1,MyArray(X),"T") > 0 then
        Wscript.Echo MyArray(X)
    End if
Next
```

My Test file contained this:

```
hello 
World
This
Is
Text
```

The VBS file popped up 2 message boxes, one with "Text" and one with "This"

You can DIM them if you want:

```
Dim objFSO
Dim objTextFile
Dim X
Dim MyArray
```

But VBS doesn't support types so don't try Dim X as Long or anything like that.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks a lot, this does seem to do the trick. Any idea how to speed up the code? As the file contains 65k+ lines.

Comment: Well if you only want the very last instance of it you can put EXIT FOR inside the IF so it jumps out of the loop after it finds your string.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend import the data with Excel, you can use [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) library, with NPOI you can easily read Excel files in .NET.

**EDIT**:

Read txt files with VB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw67h925.aspx

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt reply.
However I cannot use excel to import the data.